# Python Pandas Combined Operations

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas to review yahoo finance data and below is a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve.
On days where there is a Trade, I've set the daily return and a trading fee. On days where there is no trade, the daily return is 1.0 (no change) and there is no fee. I have been able to calculate the Balance: `Balance = START_BALANCE * Sys_Return.cumprod()`, which gives me:

```
Trade     Sys_Return     Fee     Balance
 True        1.0          0       1000
 True        1.1         10       1100
 False       1.0          0       1100
 False       1.0          0       1100
 True        1.1         10       1210
```

I would like to be able to also subtract the trading fee from the Balance at the same time so I've tried `Balance = (START_BALANCE * Sys_Return.cumprod()) - Fee` and `Balance = (START_BALANCE * Sys_Return.cumprod()) - Fee.cumsum()` but neither are correct since pandas is first multiplying the entire series by the return and then subtracting the fee, but I need the two operations to be done together.

EDIT (added expected outcome)
Expected outcome:

```
Trade     Sys_Return     Fee     Balance
 True        1.0          0       1000
 True        1.1         10       1090
 False       1.0          0       1090
 False       1.0          0       1090
 True        1.1         10       1189
```

Basically I want this logic: Balance[x] = Balance[x-1] * Sys_Return[x] - Fee[x]

Is there a simple way to do this? I have been able to do it by iterating over the dataframe, which lets me apply both operations at each step, but I know that isn't the best way to use dataframes.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make custom function. Supposing you have dataframe like this:

```
   Trade  Sys_Return  Fee
0   True         1.0    0
1   True         1.1   10
2  False         1.0    0
3  False         1.0    0
4   True         1.1   10
```

Then:

```
def fn(start_balance, sys_return, fee):
    for r, f in zip(sys_return, fee):
        v = start_balance * r - f
        yield v
        start_balance = v


df["Balance"] = list(fn(1000, df["Sys_Return"], df["Fee"]))
print(df)
```

Creates the "Balance" column:

```
   Trade  Sys_Return  Fee  Balance
0   True         1.0    0   1000.0
1   True         1.1   10   1090.0
2  False         1.0    0   1090.0
3  False         1.0    0   1090.0
4   True         1.1   10   1189.0
```